# Need help plotting a heatmap with some basic data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to create a 2D heatmap with a very basic Pandas dataframe using seaborn, but i keep getting an error, and i have no idea where i'm going wrong - i'm still very new to python and i'm not 100% sure what the errors mean or how best to fix them. Any help would be much appreciated. here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'labels': ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q5', 'Q6', 'Q7', 'Q8', 'Q9', 'Q10'],
        'Participant 1': [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0],
        'Participant 2': [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1],
        'Participant 3': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
        'Participant 4': [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
        'Participant 5': [1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1],
        'Participant 6': [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2],
        'Participant 7': [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1],
        'Participant 8': [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0],
        'Participant 9': [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1],
        'Participant 10': [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0]
    },
).set_index('labels')

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

ax = sns.heatmap(df)
plt.show()
```

but the image doesn't display and all i get is:

```
Out[155]: <AxesSubplot:ylabel='labels'>
```

It's probably something very obvious

Comment: where are you running your code? this works for me in a jupyter notebook and in a python shell

Comment: `Out[155]: <Axes...` is after you ran `ax = sns.heatmap(df)`. Did you run `plt.show()`?

Comment: You might need `%matplotlib inline` to incorporate images in a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: so i'm using spyder. and yes, the `Out[155]: <Axes...` is after running the `ax = sns....`. plt.show() doesn't do anything